# Route not displaying correct page until refresh

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I've never run into this before. on the `/orders` page there is the list of orders. When clicking the link it should take you to that order. However there is a long pause and the browser 
re-displays the list even though the url is correct `localhost/orders/2024` . If I look at the page source it shows the order, not the order list. If I refresh the page it shows the order not the order list. It does this in both firefox and chrome.

The only thing I can thing is that laravel is caching something.

My routes file:

```
<?

Route::get('orders/{id}',['as'=>'orders.show','uses'=> 'OrdersController@show']);
Route::get('orders', ['as'=>'orders.index','uses'=>'OrdersController@index']);
```

Does anyone have any idea about what's going on? I should add it does this from other computers also

EDIT: the show method. The order show file just display's "hello"

```
public function show($id)
{
    return View::make('orders.show');
}
```

Comment: can we see your show method of the controller ?

Comment: A leading slash before orders?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code for most browsers means refresh. To check your source code, open developers tool on Chrome, click the order link and then inspect your source code on the 'Elements' tab.

Somehow your order request in the first time is not being served by 'orders/{id}' and falling back to 'orders'. So do some tests:

1) Open a new browser tab and hit: localhost/orders/2024, what do you get?

2) Use dd() to understand where you are exactly:

```
public function show($id)
{
    dd('on show!');

    return View::make('orders.show');
}

public function index()
{
    dd('on index!');

    return View::make('orders.index');
}
```

3) Check the source code of your lists page, how those links are being generated? They might being somehow confusing Laravel routing system.

4) Create a link to a product manually and check if it does the same.

Answer (score 0):

This didn't have anything to do with Laravel. It was twitter bootstrap. I haven't tracked down the problem yet but when I exclude twitter-bootstrap it works fine. Sorry, this should have been one of the first things I checked.